# Typeahead in AngularJs not working properly?

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I am using a typeahead , No matter what I type, all the suggestions are coming up. I want them to filter. (i.e if user types a, all the words with initials other than a should be filtered out from suggestion, but that is not happening)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="send" typeahead="desc as desc.Name for desc in programs">
```

I am using this link for directives : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact values to be returned in the typeahead suggestions are returned from the `in` part of the expression - in your case you are saying that typeahead should return the full `programs` array no matter what was typed in the input box. If you want to restrict results based on what was entered by a user you need to filter those results and you can use the `$viewValue` expression to do so.

In your case you could write:

```
typeahead="desc as desc.Name for desc in programs | filter:$viewValue
```

assuming that `programs` is a regular JavaScript array.

You should also have a look at the examples included on the project's demo page (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to get better feeling of what is possible.

Comment: Thank you. That exactly what I needed. Also, it does have aanything to do with the script included (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js) or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a filter for that, checkout this working example.

http://plnkr.co/edit/LT6pAnS8asnpFEd5e6Ri?p=preview

Comment: @RiteshThakur Here I have issue with searching like if I type "a" it will search list that have text like "amit, anshu, annu" after clear first search I type "n"  then instead showing new response it suggest the old name which having "n" char like "anshu, annu" and if I clear the search and type "n" again it will show the correct answer,

So can you help why its showing previous list on second search and how I can resolve it